# jquery ui datepicker not appearing on click with marionette/backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, datepicker, marionette

Using marionette and trying to display a jquery date picker. However, when I click on the input, the calendar does not appear.

This is my view:

```
const view = app.Views.Layout.extend({
template: require('./templates/template'),
ui: {
    dateInput: '#date_input',

},

onShow() {
    this.ui.dateInput.datepicker();
},
```

My template with the datepicker div:

```
        <div id="date_container" class="input_holder">
            <input type="text" id="date_input" placeholder="mm/dd/year"></input>
            <div id="date_picker_holder"></div>
        </div>
```

I would assume this would be enough for the calendar to render properly however it doesnt happen. Am I missing something in my view or my template?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ui.dateInput
```

is a selector. You need to create a jQuery object by passing this selector to it and then call `.datepicker()` on the result:

```
$(this.ui.dateInput).datepicker();
```

Comment: hm this does not work either, when I click on the field no calendar shows up

Comment: @noobguy can you create a snippet?